# Error: initramfs unpacking failed: LZMA data is corrupt

Tags: boot

I'm quite new to ubuntu, and try to set up my Pc (R5 1600, asrock x370 fatality, 16 gb ram) with linux ubuntu 18.04 LTS. This information is something i can't do anything with. The information i found was not helping, because after the blue screen of unetbootin and me pressing Install Ubuntu, the Keyboard doesnt work anymore. Also my power button doesnt work. I have to pull the Power chord.